# MySQL Select data between two String date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query

```
SELECT added_by, count(*)
FROM `voters_registration`
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(added_date, '%d-%m-%Y %r'),'%d-%m-%Y') BETWEEN '01-10-2013' AND '30-10-2013'
GROUP BY added_by HAVING count(*) > 0 ;
```

when I use

```
SELECT added_by, count(*)
FROM `voters_registration`
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(added_date, '%d-%m-%Y %r'),'%d-%m-%Y') = '01-10-2013'
GROUP BY added_by
HAVING count(*) > 0 ;
```

It work fine, but I use BETWEEN as you can at above query doesn't return the correct value. The date field is the String data type.

Comment: This is why you should fix the date formats in your database

Comment: You're doing string comparisons, this seems pretty silly. Why not remove the `STR_TO_DATE` do proper `YYYY-MM-DD` comparisons? (Or as John says, change the field type in the first place)

Answer (score 1):

When you have dates as strings and you want to compare them, then the format should always be the ANSI standard YYYY-MM-DD format (the hyphens are optional).  Strings are compared as strings, so if the limits are '01-10-2013' AND '30-10-2013' then almost anything is between them, such as '29-12-1940' and '04-02-2105'.  The ordering is as *strings*.

In your case, just convert the values to dates and do the comparison as dates:

```
SELECT added_by, count(*)
FROM `voters_registration`
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(added_date, '%d-%m-%Y %r') BETWEEN '2013-10-01' and '2013-10-30'
GROUP BY added_by
HAVING count(*) > 0 ;
```

You don't need to convert the values back to strings for the comparison.